# Micrometer counter throwing the following concurent modification error

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer

hi i have messages that get published and micrometer that keeps count. However recently i have noticed the following warning:

```
io.micrometer.shaded.reactor.core.publisher.Operators
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967)
    at io.micrometer.shaded.reactor.core.publisher.Operators.onDiscardMultiple(Operators.java:565)
    at io.micrometer.shaded.reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.cancel(FluxBufferPredicate.java:174)
    at io.micrometer.shaded.reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.cancel(FluxMap.java:160)
    at io.micrometer.shaded.reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnBackpressureLatest$LatestSubscriber.cancel(FluxOnBackpressureLatest.java:99)
    at io.micrometer.shaded.reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.cancel(FluxMap.java:160)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to upgrade to the latest version of Micrometer?